# Is it possible to get into a funded master's-level graduate program by applying to labs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, japan, south-korea

I graduated from a third-tier university majoring in Aviation engineering with a 3.2 GPA. I want to go to graduate school in order to pursue my dream to become a researcher/research engineer. I landed a research assistant position at another campus right after graduating. My plans were to learn and publish papers (which I did) as I waited for the right opportunity.

After gathering information regarding scholarships, a fully-funded scholarship requires a GPA above 3.5. I talked about my concern to my current professor and he said I'm qualified to enter graduate school with my current experience. He advises me to apply for labs that have my field of interest.

Is it possible to get into graduate school by applying to labs? Do I get fully-funded by the lab? Is it really a thing?

I am mainly interested in graduate programs in Korea or Japan.

Comment: "a fully-funded scholarship requires a GPA above 3.5."  This is not generally true.

Comment: "by applying to labs?"  Depends on the country.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist So it's different everywhere? How do I know if I could apply to those labs?

Comment: Check their website, or tell us the country.  Probably someone has asked already on this site.

Comment: I aim to get into Korea or Japan

Comment: In Japan, most students have no financial support/scholarship for their master's program. It is competitive to have a have a scholarship...